# How to listen to a new document in a collection in MongoDB using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, listener, document

If a users adds a new document to a collection in MongoDB, I want to listen to that change and reflect that newly entered document on a page using AngularJS without requiring the page to get reloaded again. Just like it happens in gmail or stackoverflow.

Could somebody tell me if its possible to be done using AngularJS.

I know `$scope.$watch` could read for changes in a scoped model in a form field.

Could somebody guide me on how it could be done, if it could be done using AngularJS?

I am using NodeJS, MongoDB, Mongoose, ExpressJS and AngularJS in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will probably have to use a socket connection between the server and the client, and it is not related to which JavaScript framework you are using. Sure you can implement the client-side with Angular.js (or any JavaScript framework), but you will also have to handle this in the server-side.

If you are using node.js as a server, and you want to support older browser versions, consider to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) which allows you to easily establish sockets.

If not, you can use HTML5 websockets, [read about it hear](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).